# Regex Search Pattern

Tags: regex

I am searching a text file consisting of single words on each line for the following:

Lines that have two consecutive a’s in them but which don’t start with an a

```
import re
import sys

pattern = '^[^Aa][A-Za-z]*[Aa]{2}'

regexp = re.compile(pattern)

inFile = open('words.txt', 'r')
outFile = open('exercise04.log', 'w')

for line in inFile:
    match = regexp.search(line)
    if match:
        outFile.write(line)

inFile.close()
outFile.close()
```

My main concern is my regex search pattern rather than the python itself. I understand the ^[^Aa] at the start stops the first character from being 'A' or 'a', but is there a better way of breaking out of this statement to check for two consecutive 'a's in each word than I have used?

Comment: Are you looking for lines that end in consecutive As, or can they be anywhere in the line?

Comment: Also note that you can simplify your regex by using `re.IGNORECASE` in your call to `compile`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern looks fine.

If you want to make sure the first character is a letter, use

```
pattern = '^[B-Zb-z][A-Za-z]*[Aa]{2}'
```